# Marshmallow does not show my custom analog clock widget

Tags: android-widget, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have created custom analog clock which I want to display in the widget. This analog clock is visible in Api 16+ but not visible in Marshmallow (Api 23). Marshmallow allowing to create the widget but does not display my analog clock on the home screen.
Is there any permission in marshmallow to show my custom analog widget??
This is my Widget Class

```
'public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {
private Intent mUpdateService;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {      if(intent.getAction().equals(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DISABLED)) {
        mUpdateService = new Intent();}else{
        if (mUpdateService == null)
            mUpdateService = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
        context.startService(mUpdateService);
 }
}
    public static class UpdateService extends Service {
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        private boolean isScreenOn = true;
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String key = intent.getAction();
            if (key.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                isScreenOn = true;
                updateWidget();
            } else if (key.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                isScreenOn = false;
            } else if (isScreenOn) {
                updateWidget();
            }
        }
    };
    public RemoteViews mRemoteViews;
    public WidgetAnalogClock widgetAnalogClock;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        widgetAnalogClock = new WidgetAnalogClock(getApplicationContext());

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);}
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    updateWidget();}
    private void updateWidget(){
        WidgetAnalogClock myView=new WidgetAnalogClock(getApplicationContext());
        mRemoteViews=new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout);
        myView.measure(150, 150);
        myView.layout(0, 0, 750, 750);
        myView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = myView.getDrawingCache();
        mRemoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.customClock, bitmap);
        AppWidgetManager.getInstName(this, Widget.class), mRemoteViews);
        bitmap = myView.getDrawingCache();
        mRemoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.customClock, bitmap);}
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}`